# Простая смена классов JS

Tags: javascript, классы

У меня есть валидация с помощью регулярки, где я проверяю совпадают ли условия с введенными данными. Сейчас показан пример где нужно ввести логин длинной от 3 до 16 символов. И в случае чего добавлять bootstrap классы danger или success (Изначально ничего нет). Только вот схема получилась очень большая, я пытался сделать ее еще меньше заранее удаляя определенный класс. Только вот удалить его js не дает если он не существует. А иначе схема просто не работает. Вот код

```
$('#login').keyup(function(){
 //Проверяем длинну логина 
    var str = $(this).val();
    var result = str.search(/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/);
    if(result != 0){
        if($('#login_lenght_rule').hasClass('list-group-item-success')){
            $('#login_lenght_rule').removeClass('list-group-item-success');
            $('#login_lenght_rule').addClass('list-group-item-danger');
        }
        else{
            $('#login_lenght_rule').addClass('list-group-item-danger');
        }
    }  
    else{
        if($('#login_lenght_rule').hasClass('list-group-item-danger')){
            $('#login_lenght_rule').removeClass('list-group-item-danger');
            $('#login_lenght_rule').addClass('list-group-item-success');
        }
        else{
            $('#login_lenght_rule').addClass('list-group-item-success');
        }
    }
   return false; 
});
```

Пришлось добавить еще 2 условия которые проверяют существует ли определенный класс, помогите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать эту схему не такой громоздкой. Заренее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую с простого:

1. Для начала один и тот же селектор `$('#login_lenght_rule')` запишем в переменную, чтобы каждый раз не дергать регулярки внутри *Jquery*.  А также, заметим, что в условиях есть повторяющиеся места: внутри первого - **всегда** добавляется класс `list-group-item-danger`, вне зависимо от условия, в другом - `list-group-item-success`. Это упрощается до такого условия:

   ```
   let loginField = $('#login_lenght_rule');
   if(result != 0){    
       if(loginField.hasClass('list-group-item-success'))
           loginField.removeClass('list-group-item-success');  

       loginField.addClass('list-group-item-danger');  
   } else {
       if(loginField.hasClass('list-group-item-danger'))
           loginField.removeClass('list-group-item-danger');       

       loginField.addClass('list-group-item-success'); 
   }
   ```
2. `removeClass` сработает без ошибок, даже если класса нет в элементе, поэтому проверка на `hasClass` в данном случае не нужна. Получаем:

   ```
   let loginField = $('#login_lenght_rule');
   if(result != 0){    
       loginField.removeClass('list-group-item-success');      
       loginField.addClass('list-group-item-danger');  
   } else {
       loginField.removeClass('list-group-item-danger');               
       loginField.addClass('list-group-item-success'); 
   }
   ```
3. Всё свелось к тому, что мы просто при условии один класс удаляем, другой добавляем. Это можно вынести в функцию и вызывать её. А `if` заменить тернарником:

   ```
   let loginField = $('#login_lenght_rule');
   result != 0 
       ? switchElementClass(loginField, 'list-group-item-success', 'list-group-item-danger')
       : switchElementClass(loginField, 'list-group-item-danger', 'list-group-item-success');  

   function switchElementClass(el, from, to) {
       $(el).removeClass(from).addClass(to);
   }
   ```
4. У *Jquery* есть метод [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), который уже делает подобный функционал. У него в методе первым параметром можно написать класс, который нужно переключать, а вторым - булево значение, которое определяет включить класс или удалить. Как итог, всё можно свести к этому:

   ```
   let loginField = $('#login_lenght_rule');
   loginField.toggleClass('list-group-item-success', result === 0);
   loginField.toggleClass('list-group-item-danger', result !== 0);
   ```

   Рабочий пример:

```js
$('#login').keyup(function(){
   //Проверяем длинну логина 
    var str = $(this).val();
    var result = str.search(/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/);

    let loginField = $('#login_lenght_rule');
    loginField.toggleClass('list-group-item-success', result === 0);
    loginField.toggleClass('list-group-item-danger', result !== 0);
});
```

```css
.list-group-item-success {
  color: green;
}

.list-group-item-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="login">
<div id="login_lenght_rule">Текст</div>
```

Comment: let loginField = $('#login_lenght_rule');
        if(result != 0){    
            loginField.removeClass('list-group-item-success');      
            loginField.addClass('list-group-item-danger');  
        } else {
            loginField.removeClass('list-group-item-danger');               
            loginField.addClass('list-group-item-success'); 
        }

Вот это помогло, А вариант с тогглом работает неправильно, Там просто 1 класс danger не дает другому классу существовать

Comment: @emirlan1 да, я немного некорректно прописал условие в конце. Смотри еще раз. Я пример добавил. В итоге всё же можно до 3-ёх строк код сократить ;-)

Comment: Это гениально, большое спасибо!