# Однотипные функции

Tags: javascript, функции

В коде ниже представлена одна из множества однотипных функций. Нужно объединить их в одну и сделать задаваемым как параметр номер функции (в коде это цифра 21), основная проблема в этом. То есть вместо 21 нужен динамичный параметр, задаваемый при вызове функции (например achnew(21)).

```
function achnew21() {
if (ach21 === 0) {
    let x = document.getElementById("achnew21");
    let p = Da;
    p = Math.floor(p);

    if (p >= 100) {
        p = 100;
        x.textContent = "Выполнено - " + p + "%";
        if (ach21 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("Da").textContent = "x" + Da;
            ach21 += 1;
        };
    }
    else document.getElementById("achnew21").textContent = p + "%";

    x.style.width = p + "%";
}
else {
    let y = document.getElementById("achvmntbg21");
    y.style.background = "#f7f7ff";
    let x = document.getElementById("achnew21");
    x.style.width = 100 + "%";
    document.getElementById("achnew21").textContent = "Выполнено - 100%";
}
```

}

Comment: что за переменная ach21 ? Откуда берется? А откуда функция вызывается? Приложите разметку страницы

Comment: Глобальная переменная ach21 (их 1-21), функция вызывается из скрипта (это имеет значение?), зачем тут разметка страницы?

Comment: Если спрашиваю - значит имеет значение. В том числе и то, откуда и как вызывается и разметка. Потому что помимо айдишников есть еще объединение элементов по классу, которым можно воспользоваться

Comment: Зачем у вас заведена аж 21 переменная вместо того чтобы создать например массив?

Comment: Советую всё же приложить html разметку в вопрос, код, откуда эти функции вызываются, сказать что в находится переменных `ach` и поставить в вопрос метку [tag:инспекция-кода]. Тогда можно получить адекватный ответ

Comment: Эх зря, зря принял ответ. А ведь могли сделать конфетку. Как у вот этого парня https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/997643/199253 в итоге сделали из почти 20 строк - три. Удачи с костылестроением))

Comment: С помощью этого ответа я сделал пару функций (одно не обойтись было) и удалил целый файл js (около 500 строк)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступ к глобальным переменным можно получить через объект window:

```
function achnew(i) {
  if (window[`ach${i}`] === 0) {
...
```

Answer (score -5):

Ну я в таких ситуациях пробовал через eval делать, но что-то мне подсказывает что это говнокод будет)
К примеру:

```
for(let i = 1; i<=21; i++) {
 eval("function achnew"+i+"() {if (ach"+i+" === 0) {let x = document.getElementById('achnew"+i+"'); let p = Da; p = Math.floor(p);if (p >= 100) { p = 100; x.textContent = 'Выполнено - ' + p + '%';if (ach"+i+" === 0) {document.getElementById('Da').textContent = 'x' + Da; ach"+i+" += 1;};}else document.getElementById('achnew"+i+"').textContent = p + '%';x.style.width = p + '%';}else {let y = document.getElementById('achvmntbg"+i+"');y.style.background = '#f7f7ff';let x = document.getElementById('achnew"+i+"');x.style.width = 100 + '%';document.getElementById('achnew"+i+"').textContent = 'Выполнено - 100%';}}");
}
```

Ну или вызов функций:

```
for(let i = 1; i<=21; i++) {
 eval("achnew"+i+"()");
}
```